# Extract function argument from string

Tags: python

I have something as follows:

```
mystring="myobject"
def foo(object):
    pass
```

And I would like to call `foo(myobject)` using `mystring` directly, in the same way like `getattr(myclass, "mymethod")`.

Any help would be welcome. Thanks

Comment: Can you detail more about what you need? Maybe the syntax you think should exist. I'm not clear whether you are looking for `exec()` function or a way to get argument of `foo()` inside `foo()` using something like `getattr()`. I can't think of a context where you will find the 2nd one handy.

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve the value of `myobject`from the module where it is defined with `getattr`. If it is in the main module, this should work:

```
import __main__

mystring = 'This is a test.'

def foo(object):
    print object

variableName = 'mystring'
foo(getattr(__main__, variableName))
variableName = 'variableName'
foo(getattr(__main__, variableName))
```

This should print

> This is a test.
>
> variableName

The import of the main module is necessary for variables from the main scope.

Edit: You can also get the content of the string with very dangerous `eval()`. Just replace `foo(getattr(__main__, variableName))` with `foo(eval(variableName))`.

Comment: __How is this different from `foo(mystring)`?__ Yes it is, if there is some other `mystring` residing in a scope closer to `foo()`.

Comment: My code looks up for variable named `mystring`. The reason for that is, that you could use a variable instead of a string literal. See my edit.

Comment: I've updated my post. If you use the content of  `mystring` multiple times, you should parse it once with `myvalue = eval(mystring)`, and use `myvalue` as parameter.

Comment: @macmoonshine Thank you for the answer, except that I don't want ` object ` to be a string. 
To clarify: Let's say I have  `mystring = '[ (1,1), (2,2), (3,3) ]'`  , I want to call  `foo([ (1,1), (2,2), (3,3) ])`  . There is the possibility to use 
 `exec('foo('+mystring+')' )` , but if foo had many arguments or the list inside mystring was used frequently, that wouldn't be quite efficient, and the  `exec` is quite annoying with the `return` .

Comment: Did you see my edit and my comment? What do you mean with your last sentence?